# Can one go to a public gathering during the nine days?

Tags: nine-days, three-weeks

I believe there is a restriction against going to public gatherings during Sfeira (like movies or plays). Does this apply to the nine days? Chabad doesn't seem to think so (http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/144573/jewish/The-Three-Weeks.htm

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/144574/jewish/The-Nine-Days.htm) but I find it hard to believe. Did they leave it out, or is there really no restriction?

Comment: I think "public gatherings" refers to those that evoke joy by being at such events. It, generally, follows restrictions similar to those that apply to those that mourn parents during the 1st year. E.g., one should not attend a concert or a sports event. Movies & plays would probably be in the same category.